# Open inner fragment on clicking a button

Tags: android, android-fragments

In My application I have 5 tabs.
In 1st tab when user clicks a button I need to go to 2nd tab which contain 3 fragments.

1) List Fragment 
2) Details Fragment and 
3) Result Fragment

When user click on a button I want to go directly to the Details Fragment, and when clicks back it should go to the list.

```
Fragment fragment = ListDetailsFragment.newInstance(((MyApp) MyApp.getContext()).getCurrentItemsList().get(0));
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_fragment_container, fragment,
                    fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to go to Details fragment once a button is clicked inside 1st Tab?

Comment: your problem is on back click it is not going to list?

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of calling getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() call getActivity().getchildfragmentmanager()

```
Fragment fragment = ListDetailsFragment.newInstance(((MyApp) MyApp.getContext()).getCurrentItemsList().get(0));
                getActivity().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_fragment_container, fragment,
                        fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() is needed when there exists a viewpager element inside a fragment. Not otherwise its use is needed. So there is no point is making this change.